# Filtrar imagens por categoria com Checkbox AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, imagem

Preciso `filtrar` **HOMEM** e **MULHER**. Na lista de filtro, aparecem 4 itens, sendo que deveria aparecer **somente 2(homem e mulher)**, ou seja, por categoria.

Outro problema é que o filtro é por `ng-show="picture.checked"` e isso me trás somente **1 imagem por check**, preciso que venha `POR CATEGORIA`, ou seja, quando eu clicar em mulher aparecer duas imagens, pois há duas imagens de mulher com a mesma categoria e o mesmo vale para o homem.

### O que já tenho:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.devList = [
     { categoria: "mulher", img: "http://extra.globo.com/incoming/14942281-f88-b8b/w448/Elisabeth-Reyes-mulher-Sergio-Sanchez.jpg" },
    { categoria: "mulher", img: "http://extra.globo.com/incoming/14942281-f88-b8b/w448/Elisabeth-Reyes-mulher-Sergio-Sanchez.jpg" },
    { categoria: "homem", img: "http://dicasmodafeminina.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/qualidades-de-homem-ideal-autoconfianca.jpg" },
    { categoria: "homem", img: "http://dicasmodafeminina.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/qualidades-de-homem-ideal-autoconfianca.jpg" }
  ];
  
  
  $scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    console.log('Push Notification Change', $scope.pushNotification.checked);
  };
  
  $scope.pushNotification = { checked: true };
  $scope.emailNotification = 'Subscribed';
  
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Checkboxes</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Checkboxes</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
             
    <ion-content>
      
      <div class="list">
        
        <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in devList"
                      ng-model="item.checked" 
                      ng-checked="item.checked">
          {{ item.categoria }}
        </ion-checkbox>
      
        
      </div>
      
        
      <div class="imgs" ng-repeat="picture in devList" ng-show="picture.checked">
            <img width="200" ng-src="{{picture.img}}" width="100%" ng-click="showImage($index)"/>
       </div>
      
    </ion-content>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alguém para ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, refiz seu código adicionando uma lib e criando um filtro para resolver os dois problemas.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','angular.filter'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filtro = [];
  $scope.devList = [
    { categoria: "mulher", img: "http://extra.globo.com/incoming/14942281-f88-b8b/w448/Elisabeth-Reyes-mulher-Sergio-Sanchez.jpg" },
    { categoria: "mulher", img: "http://extra.globo.com/incoming/14942281-f88-b8b/w448/Elisabeth-Reyes-mulher-Sergio-Sanchez.jpg" },
    { categoria: "homem", img: "http://dicasmodafeminina.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/qualidades-de-homem-ideal-autoconfianca.jpg" },
    { categoria: "homem", img: "http://dicasmodafeminina.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/qualidades-de-homem-ideal-autoconfianca.jpg" }
  ];

  //função utilizada no filter do ng-repeat
  $scope.devListFilter = function () {
    return $scope.devList.filter(function (item) {
      return $scope.filtro.indexOf(item.categoria) !== -1;
    });
  };
  $scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    console.log('Push Notification Change', $scope.pushNotification.checked);
  };
  
  $scope.pushNotification = { checked: true };
  $scope.emailNotification = 'Subscribed';
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
 
 <title>Checkboxes</title>

 <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

 <!-- angular-filter.js utilizado para groupBy do checkbox -->
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 
 <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
   <h1 class="title">Checkboxes</h1>
 </ion-header-bar>
    
 <ion-content>
   
   <div class="list">
   
   <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="(key, value) in devList | groupBy:'categoria' track by $index"
       ng-model="filtro[$index]" ng-true-value="{{key}}" ng-false-value="" 
       ng-checked="check">
    {{ key }}
   </ion-checkbox>
   </div>

  <!-- ng-repeat utilizando uma função -->
   <div class="imgs" ng-repeat="picture in devListFilter(devList)">
   <img width="200" ng-src="{{picture.img}}" width="100%" ng-click="showImage($index)"/>
   </div>
   
 </ion-content>
 <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sabe fazer com que esses check fiquem true e as imagens surjam na tela logo de cara para o usuário?

Comment: javascript:
$scope.filtro = []; -> $scope.filtro = ["homem","mulher"];

html:
ng-checked="checked" -> ng-checked="true"

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar isso:

```
ng-repeat="picture in devList | filter:item.checked as results"
```

Dica: você pode deixar o trecho "as results" opcional para reutilizar os resultados, mais o `filter:item.checked` é o que você esta querendo.